# Passing parameters VUE using promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm having trouble passing value of `then parameter` but when I `console.log(url)` it's returning a value

```
var x =""

export default{

firebase(){
return {
    menu : db.ref('menu')
}
},


    data(){
        return {
        menu : [],
        sampleVar : ""
        }

    },methods: {
        getURL(imageUri){
            var starsRef = sb.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hse-delights.appspot.com/o/'+imageUri);
             starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                x = url;
                this.sampleVar = url;
                console.log(url);
            }) 
            return x;

        }
    }

}
```

even I tried `return this.sampleVar` I can't get the value, am I missing something to pass a parameters? please help, thank you very much

my Template is

```
            <div class="menuList__item" v-for="food in menu">
                <div class="menuList__color pr">
                    <div class="menuList__img">
                        <img class="menuList__path" :src="getURL(food.mPath)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="menuList__details pr">
                        <strong class="menuList__name"> {{food.mName}} </strong>
                        <div class="menuList__description">{{food.mDesc}}</div>
                        <div class="pa menuList__price">P400.00</div>
                        <div class="pa menuList__category">Rice Dishes </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either arrow function or assign a variable to `this` before the call. The `this` in the context of the callback function is the object that made the API call, not the vue component.

So:

```
getURL(imageUri){
        var self = this;
        var starsRef = sb.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hse-delights.appspot.com/o/'+imageUri);
         starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            x = url;
            self.sampleVar = url;
            console.log(url);
        }) 
        return x;

    }
```

Or

```
getURL(imageUri){
        var starsRef = sb.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hse-delights.appspot.com/o/'+imageUri);
         starsRef.getDownloadURL().then( url => {
            x = url;
            this.sampleVar = url;
            console.log(url);
        }) 
        return x;

    }
```

I prefer using the second option as I like the arrow syntax, though.

EDIT: By the way, when you return `x` at the end, it actually hasn't changed, as that will only happen in the callback. You'd probably be better off refactoring the code so that `x` is actually a property of the component and accessing its value from the template, if that's the objective.

EDIT 2: I understand now. What you want to do should be done by referencing a property directly and loading the urls at the start.

I'd do it after retrieving the data from firebase, like this (I'm assuming you're using `vuefire` which seems to be the case):

```
firebase () {
  return {
    menu: {
      asObject: false,
      source: db.ref('menu'),
      readyCallback () {
        Promise.all(this.menu.map(
          food => sb.refFromURL('...' + food.mPath).getDownloadURL()
        )).then(urls => {
          this.menu = this.menu.map((food, index) => {
            food.imgURL = urls[index]
            return food
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your HTML, you'd only reference:

```
<img class="menuList__path" :src="food.imgURL">
```

Comment: I still get the error `ReferenceError: x is not defined`, what do you mean by refactoring? thanks

Comment: Where are you using `x`? I don't see it used in your code.

Comment: `:src="getURL(food.mPath)"` i want this to become the value of `url`

Comment: I edited my answer with what could be a better way to approach the problem.